# Generate Jacoco code coverage report for individual unit tests using gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, jacoco

Gradle 'Jacoco' plugin's 'jacocoTestReport' generates code coverage report for all the unit tests.

How should I proceed to create a gradle task to generate 'Jacoco' code coverage reports of each unit test individually?

HelloWorld.java

HelloWorldTest.java contains Test1, Test2, Test3 methods

I want to generate individual Jacoco code coverage report for Test1, Test2, Test3 methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During running of the tests, Jacoco instruments the classes and records what was called. The task of type `JacocoReport` then just takes these results and makes an XML, HTML or CSV report out of them.

So to get what you want, you need to add several `Test` tasks that execute the single tests and then add several `JacocoReport` tasks that point to the different result files, then you can generate these reports in one run.

If you only want to do this manually, I think you can just call Gradle like `gradlew test --tests HelloWorld.Test1 jacocoTestReport`.

In the latter case it might be necessary to also set `test { jacoco { append false } }` to not have the results of former runs in the report.